# Python Output to File Higher Floating Point Precision

Tags: python, file-io, floating-point, precision

The following:

```
>>>import struct
>>>struct.unpack('!d', ('40d11998e5035288').decode('hex'))[0]
>>>
>>>17510.3889778429
```

I would like to be able to print the value 17510.3889778429 to a .csv output file. For some reason, when I write this to a file, it rounds the decimal and only writes:

```
17510.3889778
```

How would I print this with higher precision?

Thanks,
Ned

Comment: where's the code for writing the file?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  This is a known issue that's already fixed in the most recent versions of Python (e.g., 2.7.3);  see http://bugs.python.org/issue13573

Comment: Incidentally, looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455253 is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python's csv module, the documentation says that  non-string data is formatted using `str()`, and that seems to be where the truncation is happening. So one thing you could do is define your own class that stringizes the way you want:

```
class myFloat( float ):
    def __str__(self):
        return "%.12f"%self

 x = myFloat( 17510.3889778429 )
 print "%s"%x
```

Yields:

```
17510.388977842900
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string using any appropriate method and write the string to the CSV.

```
>>> x = 17510.3889778429
>>> s = str(x)
>>> s
'17510.3889778'
>>> s = '%17.11f' % x
>>> s
'17510.38897784290'
```